# html - My link inside a clickable area is not clickable

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have a clickable collapsible area (click enables the user to expand a text)
Within this clickable area I wish to add a link ("My link" in the code below) to perform another action.
My problem is that my button link is not clickable.

I have search through stack overflow and found similar questions but no validated answer.

Thanks.

```
<div>
        <a aria-controls="collapse2" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2" role="button"><br>
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr >
                            <td class="pink">some text</td>
                            <td class="pink"><a href="/....">My link</a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: You can not have an `<a>` tag inside another `<a>` tag

Comment: Write [real HTML](https://validator.w3.org/nu/) before worrying why it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how and what to ask. In this case, the HTML you present is not valid so you will need to re-factor it before we can help. It is likely an [X/Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) anyway so please descibe what you want to see rather than what you hope your code does: "How do I align A and B inside a collapsible ...xxx ...."

Comment: if you want a button then use a `<button>` instead of a `<a>`. this is invalid HTML

Comment: Thank you @caramba for your best answer. The code I have shared here is extracted from a longer and fully functional code that comes from Drupal and boostrap. Maybe this is the  reason why my question is so badly explained and received. I should have post my question on drupal stack exchange. Know I know that a <a> tag cannot be inside another <a> tag.

Answer (score 0):

don't use  element or don't use it for wrapping something where you need links or buttons

to use another elements for toggle collapsed bloks use data-toggle="collapse" and data-target="#collapse2"

```
<div aria-controls="collapse2" aria-expanded="false" class="collapsed" data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse2" role="button"><br>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr >
                    <td class="pink">some text</td>
                    <td class="pink"><a href="/....">My link</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @caramba for your best answer. The code I have shared here is extracted from a longer code that comes from a Drupal and boostrap. Maybe this a reason why my question is so badly explained and received. Know I know that a <a> tag cannot be inside another <a> tag.

Comment: What does wparring mean.